# Understanding the .length property

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could someone please explain what the `.length` property is doing in the following code:

```js
let sentenceCount = 0;
betterWords.forEach(word => {
  if (word[word.length-1] === '.' || word[word.length-1] === '!') {
    sentenceCount++;
  }
});
```

I understand the basic idea of what `.length` does, but when I try to print out `word[word.length]`, it prints out as `undefined`. If I print out `word[word.length-1]`, then I get the `.` and `!` in the text. I'm not understanding what `word[word.length-1]` actually is so that when `-1` is attached it gets the characters on the end.

Thank you in advance for any advice on this.

Comment: What is `betterWords`?

Comment: index starts with zero. So, `'xyz'.length` would be 3 and `'xyz'[3]` will be undefined

Comment: An alternative is to use a regular expression: `if (/[.!$]/.test(word)) {/* ends with . or !*/}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: betterWords is:

let unnecessaryWords = ['extremely', 'literally', 'actually' ];

let betterWords = storyWords.filter(word => !unnecessaryWords.includes(word));

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I understand what's going on in the code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript exhibits *zero based indexing*, that is, the first element in an array or in a string is at position `0`. Therefore, an array or string of length `n` has elements going from position `0` to `n - 1`, with element at position `n` being `undefined`. This means that an array or string with `n` elements has the **last** element at `n - 1`, which is accessed as `someArrayString[n - 1]`.

`.length` returns the length of an array or a string. Hence, the last element of an array or a string is found at `someArrayString.length - 1` which is accessed as `someArrayString[someArrayString.length - 1]`.

From the code, it can be inferred that `word` is a `string`. Therefore, the line `word[word.length-1]` accesses the last char (letter) in the `word` (although it actually accesses the last [*code unit*](http://xahlee.info/js/js_string_byte_sequence.html#:~:targetText=JavaScript%20string%20is%20sequence%20of,code%20unit%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20character.)
 but in ASCII a code unit correspond with a 1 byte ASCII char).

For example, the string `var word = "JavaScript"` has length `10`. With `J` at position `0` and `t` at position `9`. In other words, `word[0] == 'J'` and `word[word.length - 1] == 't'`

Comment: Please don't associate strings with arrays, they are very different things. Also, *length* is the number of code units in the string. Since some characters require two code units, it doesn't necessarily reflect the number of characters.

Comment: @RobG you're right. Just tried not to overwhelm the OP. I edited it, in fact, I should have written it like so from the beginning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `word = 'People';`

`word.length` would return `6` which is the character number in your `word`.

Since arrays (in this case string because .length can be used in strings too) start from index `0`, `word.length-1` would give you the 5th element of your string, which is the last character of your `word`.

In your code, `if (word[word.length-1] === '.' || word[word.length-1] === '!')` checks if the last character of a word is a dot (.) or exclamation point (!) so you can count how many sentences there are in a given string.

Answer (score 0):

`word.length-1` - Returns the last index in the word

**Explanation**

```
word= 'test!';
console.log(word[word.length-1])
```

OUTPUT - !

The Length of word = 5

We need to get the last index of the word i.e `word[4]` as the array indexing starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

Your `.length` property returns [the length of the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length). The string itself is a one-dimensional array with elements of the type character so using `.length` gives the size of the array. Arrays use zero-based indexing.

So in your case `word[word.length-1]` returns the last element/character of the array and `word[word.length]` goes beyond the bounds of the array and that's why it prints out `undefined`.

Here's a playground you can test it.

```js
const string = "Just a test.";

//get the last element
console.log(string[string.length-1]);
//trying to get an element outside the bounds of the array
console.log(string[string.length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, In your code I assume that `betterWords` is an array because you are using `forEach`.

And also assume the `betterWords` array is something like,

```js
betterWords = ['word.','words!','hello','world'];
```

**Length Property**

The length property returns the length of `array` or `string`.

```js
let myArray = [0,5,6,8,9];
let myString = 'hello';

console.log(myArray.length) // 5 | because myArray has total 5 elements.
console.log(myString .length) // 5 | because myString has total 5 characters.
```

**Index**

Then `index` tells us the position of an **element in an array** or a **character in a string**.

The `index` is starting from 0.

```js
let myString = 'hello';

/*
 * h e l l o
 * - - - - -
 * 0 1 2 3 4
 */
console.log(myString[0]); // h | because h is 0 index of hello
```

So now you can see the `length` of the word `hello` is `5`. But the `last index` of the word hello`is`4`. Which means **the last index = length - 1**

**That's why here we are subtracting 1 from length to get the last index.**

```js
console.log(word[word.length-1]);
```